# Which field or property is causing the exception to occur in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jpa

I use JPA/Hibernate for persisting data,
and for example, i have a class named 'book' that 'ISBN' field is uniqe and 'Page' is int.

when user set this fields by mistake data (duplicate number for isbn or a string for page), and when i use session.save(book1) to persist this entity, a exception is thrown.

I want show to user the source of the problem. for example, change background of JTextFieldISBN to red.

Now, which field is causing the exception to occur?
In other words, how do understand that which field is mistake and cause this exception?

Comment: This should be validated before even trying to persist the book. BTW, how could you set store a string (page) into an int field? Don't rely on hibernate exceptions to do this.

Comment: Right, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting NonUniqueException is case of duplicate fields, for other fields would recommend to do a validation before persisting in database.

Hope this helps to solve current problem in hand.

Cheers !!